# Risks of updating composer from 1.10.24 to 2.1.0 on a Magento 2 instance

Tags: composer, composer-update, magento24

I want to update Magento from 2.4.1 to 2.4.4-p2 and I need to do other updates first, including updating the Composer from 1.10.24 (current version) to at least 2.1.0.

The issue is that my production environment is on the same server as the development environment and updating the Composer will also impact production. I don't know if updating the composer on a subdomain level is possible, but I don't think so.

What would be the main risks in updating the composer from 1.10.24 to 2.1.0 in the production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install keep Composer 1 and Composer 2 on the same server, look at this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65273012/keep-composer-1-2-both-in-same-machine

Even if you update Composer from version 1 to version 2, you can roll back to version 1 simply and quickly: `composer self-update --1`

Or back to Composer version 2 after that:
`composer self-update --2`

You can also "update" to a specific version just by passing the version number to self-update:

`composer self-update 1.10.24`

or `composer self-update 2.1.0`

I would like to say that is no risk at all even if you update Composer from version 1 to version 2.